# React Native push notifications in XCode and Firebase

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an app in React Native and I use Firebase connected via the react-native-firebase package. I want to implement phone authentication and to do so I need push notifications to be enabled

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#enable-phone-number-sign-in-for-your-firebase-project

In XCode under the Signing&Capabilites tab when I click add capability button there is no option for Push Notifications, I found the tread however that says I should uncheck the "Automatically manage signing" checkbox

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127698

And ok, when I do that I have a lot more options to choose from, including Push Notifications, but should I? Are these push notifications implicitly checked by default together with all other options that are not visible with this checkbox checked? Or should I diable "automativally manage signing" to be able to implement Push Notifications in Firebase.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
To enable pushNotification in firebase need to follow steps 
open firebase console 
navigate to cloud mesanging 


 1. Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)Enabled is Enabled 

 In Apple app configuration

 2. APNs Certificates or APNs Authentication Key one of them is requried for 
  getting push notification in ios
 
 3.Follow rnFirebase for integration [here][1]
 
 4. Xcode Setup 
    add capability in Signin & Capibility  

   1.  add Background mode capability -> check remote notificaiton.
   2.  push notification
```

Comment: Hi, Ravin Kumar thank's a lot for the reply, tell me why should I enable legacy api? And is it safe to assume that this "Automatically manage signing" setting is a no-go and I need to overwrite it to have these functionalities enabled? thanks!